# How to create range based ticks in chart js? (like in attached image)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

So I am trying to create a third axis on right like this, where I can pass range for low normal and high value, but I can't seem to find anything on how to do this on a range basis.

Here is a quick fiddle with chartjs linked and basic data to easily edit : https://jsfiddle.net/902rvd3j/

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-asxKqQghC1oBShyhiBwA+YgotaSYKxGP1rcSYTDrB0U6DxwlJjU59B67U8+5/++uFjcuVM8Hh5cokLjZlhm3Vg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
```

JS :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: 'red',        
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Every help and advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please dont abuse taggs by adding unnecesrry ones to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin api to draw anything you want on the canvas:

```js
const customPlugin = {
  id: 'customTicks',
  afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    if (opts.ticks === undefined) {
      return
    }

    const {
      ctx,
      canvas,
      scales: {
        x,
        y
      }
    } = chart;
    const {
      ticks,
      offset,
      textColor,
      fontString
    } = opts;
    const xStart = x.getPixelForValue(x.ticks[x.ticks.length - 1].value) + (offset || 0);
    const width = canvas.width - xStart;

    ticks.forEach((tick) => {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = tick.color;
      ctx.fillRect(xStart, y.getPixelForValue(tick.from), width, (y.getPixelForValue(tick.to) - y.getPixelForValue(tick.from)));

      ctx.fillStyle = textColor || 'black';
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.font = fontString || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'

      ctx.translate(xStart + width / 2, (y.getPixelForValue(tick.to) + y.getPixelForValue(tick.from)) / 2)
      ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
      ctx.fillText(tick.text, 0, 0)
      ctx.restore();
    })
  }
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 60 // Add padding on the right for the ticks to draw
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      customTicks: {
        offset: 10, // Distance between the boxes and the chartArea
        textColor: 'white',
        fontString: "30px Comic Sans MS",
        ticks: [{
            from: 2,
            to: 6,
            color: 'red',
            text: 'Low'
          },
          {
            from: 6,
            to: 12,
            color: 'green',
            text: 'Medium'
          },
          {
            from: 12,
            to: 20,
            color: 'red',
            text: 'High'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customPlugin]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi again, Lee, can you also tell me how I can pass variable in ticks value, I am having some problems figuring out how to pass y.max value in ticks, instead of hard value in this code, here is a fiddle of this code for help : https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_soni/2mrhv395/

Comment: Dont know if I understand it correctly but I think you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/aekfdwhy/2/

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I need, thanks a lot man, can't thanks you enough! Big big thanks!!

Comment: Hi again, Lee, I don't even know if it's appropriate that I am asking you for more, but I couldn't help it as I have tried all places I can.

I can't figure this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815739/how-to-use-chart-js-npm-module-to-generate-chart-through-node-using-html-ejs

Also, just so you know, I have tried to get in touch with the chartjs npm module contributors as well, but to no avail, so I was wondering if you can take a look at this, also came across your github there contributing to module. Thanks in advance, man!

Comment: Already saw the question but dont know the answer since I never used chart.js in that way with node

Comment: Okay, and thanks a lot for all the helps you have done in the last few days!